# Problem on deactivating caps lock

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb, capslock

I'm new here, so I'm sorry if I've done anything wrong.

So... I've noticed that my caps lock only deactivate when i release the key. I can activate it just by pressing the key, but to turn it off, I need to release the key that I've pressed. That really bothers me.

I tried going to xkbmap file and change the configuration of the caps lock, inserting

```
key <CAPS> {
    repeat=no,
    type[group1]="ALPHABETIC",
    symbols[group1]=[ Caps_Lock, Caps_Lock],
    actions[group1]=[ LockMods(modifiers=Lock), Private(type=3,data[0]=1,data[1]=3,data[2]=3)]
};
```

But it didn't work.

Can anyone help me with this, please? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: were you trying to follow the [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration)? In any case, if you provide a bit more info you might get quicker and better answers. Which layout are you using? where exactly did you try to insert that above section in which xkbmap file? did you get an error message? If you have more info on those questions (or any other that you may feel it might be relevant, please update your answer with them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution that works for me would be adding that CAPS LOCK definition in the symbols file from xkb, found in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`. Each layout has their file such as `us`, `de`, `fr` for US american, German and French respectively.

**FIRST**: assuming you are using the `us` layout, you can create custom symbols file and call it something like `custom`.  In there you can populate with your customizations:

```
partial xkb_symbols "caps_lock_unlock_patch" {  
    key <CAPS> {
        repeat=no,
        type[group1]="ALPHABETIC",
        symbols[group1]=[ Caps_Lock, Caps_Lock ],
        actions[group1]=[ LockMods(modifiers=Lock), Private(type=3,data[0]=1,data[1]=3,data[2]=3) ]
    };
};
```

**Second**: you go to your current layout file and include a pointer to your customizations:

```
default  partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {

    name[Group1]= "English (US)";

    key <TLDE> {    [     grave,    asciitilde  ]   };
    ...
    // rest of customization of basic US file
    ...
    key <BKSL> {    [ backslash,         bar    ]   };
    
    // include your customization here
    include "custom(caps_lock_unlock_patch)"
    // the syntax is include "NAME_OF_FILE(NAME_OF_PARTIAL_SYMBOLS_DEFINITION)"
};
```

You can also just add the chunk directly in the `us` symbols file, but I believe keeping things separated is better, specially if you want to apply the same customization to multiple layouts and the custom file should not be overwritten in a update, while the default files might be.

You may also create a whole new layout from scratch (you can always include other layouts with `include "us(basic)"` for example, and then use your custom layout instead of the default ones. Or you can manipulate a layout that you usually don't use, just in case you would like to be able to switch back to your preferred layout without any customization.

Finally, just a tip: avoid editing files directly in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/`, it is probably always better to create a folder for your customizations in your home folder and symbolic link those files to the xkb folder. And if you modify the default files, create a copy of them just in case you mess up and need to revert any changes.